# Php events calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

Basically, I am making a events calendar where a submit button is generated on a day that a event has been entered into my database. On the click of the submit button it opens a new page (events.php) which displays the details of the Event on that day.

However, my problem is that I don't know how to get the date from where the submit button is on the calendar ( the day of the month) into the query which gets the data from my database. At the moment I have just hard coded a date in to see if it works which is does.

If I'm not clear I'm happy to go over it again but It has to be dynamic so it can work for any day any month any year

Code:
Calendar_start.php (creates the calendar)

```
?php
$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showmonth);
$showyear= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showyear);

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6-(date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, $day_count, $showyear))));

echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Previous Month" onClick="javascript:last_month();"></div>';
echo '<div class="show_month">'  . date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $showmonth)) . ' ' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"><input name="button" type="submit" value="Next Month" onClick="javascript:next_month();"></div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Tues</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';


if ($pre_days != 0) { 
    for($i=1; $i<=$pre_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","pytsuemg_brodie","brodie");
mysql_select_db("pytsuemg_brodie", $con);

for ($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {

    $date = $i.'/'.$showmonth.'/'.$showyear;
    //echo $date;

    $query = "Select EventId FROM Events WHERE DateStart = '$date'";

    $num_rows = 0;
    // check if the query returns anything
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($result) 
    {

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    }

    echo '<div class="cal_day">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';
    if($num_rows > 0) 
        { 
        echo "<input type=\"submit\"value=\"View Event\" onClick=\"window.open('events.php')\">";
        }
    echo '</div>';



} //end of for loop

if ($post_days !=0) {
    for($i=1; $i<=$post_days; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }
}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

Events.php (gets the information from the databse)

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","pytsuemg_brodie","brodie","pytsuemg_brodie");



    $query=("SELECT DateStart, description FROM Events WHERE DateStart = '2/2/2014'");
    $num_rows = 0;
    // check if the query returns anything
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($result)
    {

        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }

    if($num_rows > 0) {
            while ($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $evdate = $newArray['DateStart'];
                $description = $newArray['description'];
                echo "The Date is $evdate and the description is $description <br>";
            }

    }
?>
```

show_calendar.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="calstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var currentTime = new Date ();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    showmonth = month;
    showyear = year;
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function next_month() {
    var nextmonth = showmonth + 1;
    if(nextmonth > 12) {
        nextmonth = 1;
        showyear = showyear+1;
    }
    showmonth = nextmonth;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function last_month() {
    var lastmonth = showmonth - 1;
    if(lastmonth < 1 ) {
        lastmonth = 12;
        showyear = showyear-1;
    }
    showmonth = lastmonth;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var vars= "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar"). innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialCalendar();">
<div id="showCalendar"> </div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="events"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyone, I'm really in need for help

Comment: Narrow down your problem. It is simply impossible for anything to be related to PHP, jQuery and MySQL - all at once.

Comment: Also, posting tons of source code usually does not lead to better answer. The question should be general so that the answer is useful for other people as well.

Comment: submit button -> `... onClick=\"window.open('events.php?date=$date')` then `$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['date']); $query=("SELECT DateStart, description FROM Events WHERE DateStart = '$date'");` in your `events.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you want but I think this is it:

```
     <input type=\"button\"value=\"View Event\" onClick=\"window.open('events.php?date=".$date."')\">
```

then in events.php

```
     $date=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['date']);
     $query=("SELECT DateStart, description FROM Events WHERE DateStart = '$date'");
```